Selecting rows with matching multiple columns (order doesn't matter)
I am wanting to determine the number of distinct user_ids that have the same 3 animals as any user (where order doesn't matter).
For example below, user 11 and 13 both have dog, cat, bird so they would both be counted.



user_id
Col1
Col2
Col3




11
dog
cat
bird


12
cow
dog
bird


13
cat
bird
dog



The desired output here would be



distinct_users
distinct_users_with_a_match




3
2




Do all three columns always have a value for each user_id?

Try below
with temp as (
  select
    user_id, 
    (select string_agg(col order by col) from unnest([Col1, Col2, Col3]) col) h
  from your_table 
)
select 
  (select count(distinct user_id) from temp) as distinct_users,  
  (select count(distinct user_id) from(
    select user_id from temp qualify count(distinct user_id) over(partition by h) > 1
  )) as distinct_users_with_a_match

